# Collision detection with own geometries didn't work in Three.js for me

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

I have a trouble with collision detection in the THREE.js library. Below I located a link to my example (use arrow keys to move a body object):

http://jsfiddle.net/flyenet/uJLUU/7/

In this example I want to create my own geometries (for "relief" and for "body") and detect collisions between them. When vertices of the body are located inside the relief, the red square in left top corner have opacity 1, else it's semi-transparent.

Geometry for body:

```
var up = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 0.2, 3, 1),
        down = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 0.2, 3, 1);
for (var i = 0, l = up.vertices.length; i < l; i++) {
    up.vertices[i].x *= 1.75;
    up.vertices[i].z = up.vertices[i].z * 0.5;
    down.vertices[i].x *= -0.7;
    down.vertices[i].z = -down.vertices[i].z * 2.3 + 1;
}
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(up, down);
```

Geometry for relief:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 32, 32, 1, 16, 16);
geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.PI / 2));
for (var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(i / 17),
        y = Math.floor(i / 289),
        z = i % 17;
    geometry.vertices[i].y = y === 0 ? (x - 8) * (x - 8) * 0.1 : -10;
}
```

Function to detect collision cases:

```
function test() {
    var originPoint = body.position.clone();
    for (var vi = 0, vl = body.geometry.vertices.length; vi < vl; vi++) {
        var localVertex = body.geometry.vertices[vi].clone(),
            globalVertex = body.matrix.multiplyVector3(localVertex),
            directionVector = globalVertex.subSelf(body.position),
            ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize()),
            results = ray.intersectObjects([relief]);

        if (results.length > 0 && results[0].distance < directionVector.length()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works, but there are cases, when the body is located on the relief's border and the red square is semi-transparent (instead opacity 1). It looks like this:

[image: http://s7.postimg.org/yfgs5m08r/collision.jpg]

It means, that collision detection didn't fire. Why? What should I change in my code to detect any collision cases?

Comment: I can't debug your code for you, but I would suggest that you upgrade to three.js r.61 -- your code is compatible with an older version of the library. Also, when you move vertices, and fail to correct face centroids, face normals, and face vertex normals, you will likely run into trouble.

Comment: @user2808747 - it may be unobvious that the three.js version provided by jsFiddle by default, current v54, is quite out of date. Instead, under "frameworks and extensions" choose none, and then in the HTML section, enter <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script> to always be using the most recent version of the library.